# How to do string operations with Win32 WCHAR

Tags: c++, unicode, unicode-string, wchar-t

I have a win32 project in which I'm trying to edit the characters of a WCHAR string with a custom function.

I know this stands for Wide Char and is Unicode, however I don't fully grasp how the encoding works. For example, I know UTF-8 also holds Unicode, but is it the same as a WCHAR?

I assumed the string would look something like

```
00 43 00 4f 00 44 00 45 00 00
    C     O     D     E    \0
```

And for copying it works fine to just assume the string is twice as long. However I am getting errors when, say, searching for a character, for example:

```
for(int i = wcslen(inStr) - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    WCHAR current[] = {inStr[i], inStr[i + 1], 0, 0};
    if(current == _T("/")) {
        pos = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Produces some corrupted errors. Am I making this too complicated? I understand there's probably many functions to do this, but I'd like to understand how it works, so I can make for efficient code. Thanks

Comment: By the way, please add the `c++` tag to your C++ questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Shorter Answer

The specific problem you’re having is that `current[n]` is the nth *element* in the array, not the nth *byte* of the array.  Doing pointer arithmetic like `current + n` also gives you the nth *element* after the one `current` points to.  The same is true if you declare an array of `int`, `double`, some `struct` or anything else.

So, when you declare an array `wchar_t a[] = L"!"`, then take `wcslen(a)`, you get back the count of wide characters in the array, 1.  If you try to set `i = wcslen(a) - 2;` and then take `a[i]`, `i` will be -1, which is a serious bug.

## Longer Explanation

On Windows, `WCHAR` is an alias for the standard type `wchar_t`.  You don’t say whether you’re writing in C or C++.  There are a number of functions in the C standard library to manipulate wide-character strings, in `<wchar.h>` and `<wctype.h>`.  The C++ standard library has all of these, as well as `std::wstring` in `<string>` and wide-character streams including `std::wcout`, `std::wcin` and `std::wcerr` (although Windows doesn’t fully support them).  Most Windows API functions also can accept wide-character strings.  The standard type of a wide character string is `wchar_t*`, but `WCHAR*`, `LPWSTR` and, by default on modern versions of Visual Studio, `TCHAR*` and `LPTSTR` also work.

On Windows, wide characters are little-endian UTF-16.  This is not portable, but then, neither is `WCHAR`.  On some other systems, wide characters are either big-endian UTF-16, or big- or little-endian UTF-32.  In C, the standard types `char16_t` and `char32_t` are defined in `<uchar.h>`.  In C++, they are built into the language.  If you try to pass a `char16_t*` to a function that expects a `wchar_t*`, it won’t work without a cast, or on targets other than Windows at all.

UTF-8 is a way of storing Unicode code points that’s backwards-compatible with seven-bit ASCII.  UTF-8 is an alternative representation from UTF-16 or UTF-32.  A UTF-8 string will be stored in an array of `unsigned char` or `char`, with one Unicode code point potentially needing several bytes to store it.  Actually, because of surrogate pairs, a Unicode code point potentially needs two UTF-16 objects to encode it, as well.  There are some times when it’s convenient to use a different representation (UTF-16LE is what the Windows ABI expects and what some libraries like ICU and QT use internally, and UTF-32 is the only representation that guarantees all Unicode characters will fit into a single element), but my advice is to use UTF-8 whenever you can and some other encoding whenever you have to.

## Possible solution

If you want to read backwards through a wide string, you might try this:

```
int i = wcslen(inStr); // Could be 0.

if (i > 0) { // Don't read one element past the start of the array.
  do {
    --i;
  } while ( i > 0 && inStr[i] != L'/' );
}

/* When we reach this line, i is either 0 or the index of the last slash
 * in inStr, which could also be 0.  We can test whether inStr[i] == L'/' or
 * write an if() within our loop to do something more complicated.
 */
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I am using C++. I see what you mean, I was trying to do operations on a byte array with unicode notation, but wchar_t is a 16-bit character itself. And so L'/' just returns a wide wchar_t. I was wondering though, in UTF-8, how are characters chained together? Is the last bit used to link each byte?

Comment: It’s easy to look up information on UTF-8 online, but short answer: if the high bit of a UTF-8 byte is 0, it’s an ASCII character.  Any Unicode code point above 127 is represented by a sequence of two to four bytes.  A byte starting with 110, 1110 or 11110 is the first byte of a multibyte sequence, and a byte starting with 10 continues a multibyte sequence.  That makes UTF-8 backwards-compatible with ASCII, easy to autodetect and check for validity, unaffected by endianness, and compact for many languages. Unfortunately, Windows NT came out before UTF-8, so Windows got stuck with what it has.

Comment: Thank you. This clears up quite a bit. I understand this is one of those "Google it" questions, which is why I'm downvoted, but sometimes with these specific questions, "Unicode encoding" doesn't really give me what I need